# jsf inputText validator

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, validation

Is there a way in richfaces ajaxvalidator or ajax suport a user from writting in an inputText to as soon as he writes something other than a number. 
In other words is it possible to disable the inputText field when the user inputs NaN.

for example: if the user tries to write : "11a" , is there a way to prevent the user from writting the a?
so when he presses the "a" a warning that input is not a number will appear.

This is the jsf code:

```
<h:inputText id="price" value="#{carBB.price}" required="true">
    <rich:ajaxValidator event="onkeypress"/>                
</h:inputText>
```

This is in the bean code:

```
@NotNull
private double price;

public double getPrice() {
return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
this.price = price;
}
```

In my code the warning appears when the user writes NaN but that doesn't prevent him from writing it.

Comment: Why not prevent typing in of text in by means of JavaScript? What do you need server for?

Comment: It is a bigger application that just one form of the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this that worked fine for me only allows doubles:\

In header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableKeys(e,exist)
{
    var unicode=e.keyCode;
    var value = exist.value;
    if((unicode< 0x30 && unicode != 0x2E) || unicode> 0x39) 
    {
        alert("Invalid Input should be number or \".\"");
        return false;
    }
    else if(unicode == 0x2E && value.indexOf(".")>=0)
    {
        alert("Invalid Input already contains a \".\"");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
</script>
```

In body:

```
<h:inputText id="price" value="#{carBB.price}" onkeypress="return disableKeys(event,this);"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:inputText id="myId" value="#{myBean.value}" 
             onkeypress="if((event.which &lt; 48 &amp;&amp; event.which != 44 &amp;&amp; event.which != 46) || event.which &gt; 57) return false;"/>
```

this will allow numbers, comma and dot.

Comment: I think this won't do since the field is a `double` and user probably want to add `.` symbol as well.